# Select an instance by class name with nicEdit

Tags: javascript, editor, wysiwyg, nicedit

Is there any way to select an instance with [nicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) by its class name, not only by its id?

For example:

```
<div class="myInstance1">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Sed magna dolor, faucibus ac, iaculis non, cursus et, dui. Donec non urna. Aliquam volutpat ornare augue. Phasellus egestas, nisl fermentum porttitor rutrum, magna metus rutrum risus, id fringilla magna mi nec lorem.
</div>
```

Call the nicEdit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
          var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
          myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel');
          myNicEditor.addInstance('myInstance1');
     });
</script>
```

It doesn't work this way unless the class is id. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do this as well

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the difference between an ID and a class. The command "addInstance" is looking to add a single instance and is linking that instance to the id provided. Since the id is by definition only used once per page, nicEdit can easily identify it.

However, using the class designation would possibly create multiple instances, something that this command isn't intended to do.

A solution would be to create a loop that goes through each occurrence of the class and creates a new nicEdit instance and a unique ID for that instance based upon the loop number.

The code would look something like this ... assign a class to any area you want to be a nicedit area. Loop through that class and assign a unique id to it. Then, create a new instance based upon that id. In the example below "nicinstance" is the class name.

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    var myNicEditor = new nicEditor();
    myNicEditor.setPanel('myNicPanel');
    $( ".nicinstance" ).each(function( index ) {
     $(this).attr("id","myInstance"+index);
     myNicEditor.addInstance('myInstance'+index);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for answering but I forgot to say that this element has also an id by default so this solution doesn't work. Sorry, I missed to write it.

Comment: @giokokos i don't see the point,the id would be unique, right ? all you have to do is get the existing id instead of setting the new one and create the instance...